# pyrogram - PingTask зависло

Tags: python, pyrogram

```
async def send_message(chat_id: int):
    image_files = get_image_files()
    if not image_files:
        try:
            await app.send_message(chat_id, "1")
            logger.info(f"Бот успешно отправил сообщение в чат: {chat_id}")
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Ошибка при отправке сообщения в чате {chat_id}: {e}")
    else:
        for index, image_file in enumerate(image_files):
            with open("images/" + image_file, "rb") as file:
                media_group = []
                if index == 0:
                    media_group.append(InputMediaPhoto(file, caption="photo caption"))
                else:
                    media_group.append(InputMediaPhoto(file))
                try:
                    await app.send_media_group(chat_id, media_group)
                    logger.info(f"Бот успешно отправил медиа-группу в чат: {chat_id}")
                except Exception as e:
                    logger.error(f"Ошибка при отправке медиа-группы в чате {chat_id}: {e}")
```

Вот такой код. Суть: отослать медиагруппу. Все использованные функции возвращают верные данные. Добавляю в медиагруппу файлы - ошибок нет. Но в какой-то момент все зависает на моменте:

2023-07-29 22:51:07,426 - INFO - PingTask started
PingTask started